# Receiving "failed to load component"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to load some content into a component with Vue.js. I am trying to do this with the :is attribute. I keep getting "[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: interview"

```
<todo-tabs :list="items"></todo-tabs>

<template id="interview-slot">
 //Interview Slot Content
</template>

<template id="membership-slot">
 //Interview Slot Content
</template>

<script>
Vue.component('todo-tabs', {
        template: '#todo-tabs',
        props: ['list'],
        data: function(){
            return {
                currentView: 'interview',
                components:{
                    interview:{
                        template: '#interview-slot'
                    },
                    membership:{
                        template: '#membership-slot'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
});


var vm = new Vue({
el: "#todo",
data: {
items : [
            {id: 'interview', name: 'interview', complete: true, body: 'something1', step_content: 'SOME',current: true  },
            {id: 'membership', name: 'membership', complete: true, body: 'something2', step_content: 'SOME' },
            {id: 'profile', name: 'profile', complete: false, body: 'something3', step_content: 'SOME'  },
            {id: 'handoff', name: 'handoff', complete: false, body: 'something4', step_content: 'SOME'}
        ]
    }
});
</script>
```

I really don't want to put my html in the json if possible as it content lots of form elements.

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: The only component I'm seeing being registered is todo-tabs. Interview is not.

Answer (score 0):

In this part of the code:

```
<template id="interview-slot">
  //Interview Slot Content
</template
```

You are missing the closing `>` after `</template`.

Comment: Thanks @foxdonut that was a typo when creating the question. The code was closed properly and still receiving the error